# Logic behind for-loop /while loop

Tags: c++, loops

I need help understanding the difference in logic between the while loop / for loop here's the sample code :

```
#include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
 cout << "A multiplication table:" << endl
      << "  1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9" << endl
      << "" << endl;
 for(int c = 1; c < 10; c++)
 {
      cout << c << "| ";
      for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      {
      cout << i * c << '\t';
      }
      cout << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I tried rewriting it as a while loop , but the outcome is missing information.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
  int i = 1;
int c = 1;
while (c< 10){
    cout << c <<"|";
    c++;
    while (i< 10){
        cout << i * c << '\t';
        i++;


    }
    cout << endl;
}

cin.clear();
cin.ignore();
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Someone suggested that resetting i to 1 would give the rest of the results, i'm having trouble understanding why the while loop requires a reset whereas the for loop does not.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
     dosomething;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
i=0;
while (i<n) {
   dosomething;
   i++;
}
```

The problem in your code is that you don't reset `i` to 1 in the inner loop.
Declare `int i=1` inside the loop over c, not outside of it.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
int c = 1;
while (c< 10){
    cout << c <<"|";
    c++;
    int i=1;
    while (i< 10){
        cout << i * c << '\t';
        i++;


    }
    cout << endl;
}

cin.clear();
cin.ignore();
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set i=1 to get your expected behavior in both examples. With the for loop, this is already taken care of since in the header of the for loop, there is a for(**int i = 1**; ...; ...).